# jquery data attribute get this element

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-data

I have a view with a lot of images

```
 <img src="@Path" data-img-prev="@UrlPreview" data-full-path="@UrlImage" onclick=Get()  />
```

and it render in html like this

```
<img img-prev="1.jpg" data-full-path="https://...1.jpg" src="https://...1.jpg">
<img img-prev="2.jpg" data-full-path="https://...2.jpg" src="https://...1.jpg"> 
<img img-prev="3.jpg" data-full-path="https://...3.jpg" src="https://...1.jpg">
```

I want function to get data from each element

```
function Get() {
this.getAttribute('img-path');
this.data('img-path');
```

}

It is not working please help:

> error  this.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: How do you call ttt() function??? Is it Get() function?

Comment: You have to improve your question. What is the rendered HTML? Obviously, this is not what you have posted...

Comment: give me a moment it so fast

Comment: easy to downvote hard to undownvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data attribute is called `data-full-path`, not `img-path`.

```
var result = this.getAttribute('data-full-path');
```

or since you tagged it with jQuery (assumings you're in a click handler context):

```
var result = $(this).data('full-path');
```

Comment: thank you $(this).data('full-path'); it is works and this.getAttribute('data-full-path'); error getAttribute is not a function

Comment: @user246340 You need to check if it's supported in your browser if you don't want to user jQuery: `if('getAttribute' in this)` should be enough.

Comment: it is work in ie 9-10 firefox and chrome last version I work only in this browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use `.data('full-path')` instead of `.data('img-path')`